# Conditional Probability, balls in bag.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are 5 white balls and 4 black balls in a box. Three random balls are taken out.
What's the probability that out of the 3 balls the number of black balls is odd provided that the last taken ball was black?

I understand that this is an extremely straight forward problem, but I not able to match the answer with the solution. So, I needed a second pair of eyes to check if I am correct.

Here is what I did.

Set A (# 1 or 3 black balls) = {('W', 'B', 'W') ('W', 'W', 'B') ('B', 'B', 'B') ('B', 'W', 'W')}

Set B (last black ball) = {('W', 'B', 'B') ('W', 'W', 'B') ('B', 'B', 'B') ('B', 'W', 'B')}

Hence the probability that out of the 3 balls the number of black balls is odd provided that the last taken ball was black will be

$P(A | B) = \frac{\#(A \cap B)}{\#(B)}$

$A \cap B = {('W', 'W', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'B')}$

$\Rightarrow P(A|B) = \frac{2}{4} = 0.5$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you been taught combinations?

Comment: Yes, I have been taught combinations. I learned combinations in schools that would be 30 years ago. So, surely I am rusty. Thanks for the hint to use combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sets do not consider the probability of them occurring which can be different for different sets.

Say the event of third ball being black is $B$ and event of odd number of black balls is $A$.

Outcomes where third ball is black - $\small\{2B, B\}, \{2W, B\}, \{1B 1 W, B\}$

Outcomes where we have odd number of black balls and the last ball is black - $\small \{2B, B\}, \{2W, B\}$

So, $\small P(B) = \displaystyle \frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} + \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} + 2 \cdot\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} = \frac{4}{9}$

$\small P(A\cap B) = \displaystyle \frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} + \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} = \frac{13}{63}$

So, $\small P(A|B) = \displaystyle \frac{13}{28}$